# ¿Borrar elemento de un array de session en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Me estoy volviendo loco y no doy con una solución al problema. He estado viendo en foros en inglés y de las respuestas que proponen no me funciona ninguna.
¿Alguien sabría como hacerlo?

Comment: podrias agregar el código de tu array o la forma de de obtenerlo?

Answer (score 1):

La forma de borrar elementos de la sesión en Laravel es:

Para un elemento en particular:

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

o

```
Session::forget('key');
```

Para todos los elementos de la sesión:

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

o

```
Session::flush();
```

Según la documentación oficial de Laravel: [Sesiones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#deleting-data)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu respuesta pero eso no funciona, fue lo primero que hice, y me borrar todo el array. Ya encontre la solucion. Pase mucho tiempo mirando en foros, y al parece laravel no posee un metodo para borrar elementos de un array de un session.

1- Tienes que obtener el valor del indice que quieres eleminar.
2-Lo paso por Axios.
3-Lo recupero en el controlador.
4- Hago un pull() del array se session
5- Utilizo unset(indice_eliminar)
6-Hago un put() del array.
De esta manera he conseguido eleminar elementos de un array de session.